# Dynamically create and submit a form

Tags: html, elm

I have some data in my model which I want to put into a request body and send it with a POST request. The problem is I want the browser to navigate to the request URL because the route returns a new HTML page. Normally this would be done by putting the data in a form and then using JS to submit it.

How can I do this with Elm?

Comment: If only there way a way to let the author of the question know why you think the question is bad... Sadly, the only thing you can do is press the "close" button.

Comment: From elm-lang.org fo to "Docs" > "An Introduction to Elm". Eventually you'll get to "HTTP". From here you'll read about the Http module and http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/http/latest/Http#post.

Comment: @z5h Check out the answer to this question to see why the Http module doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** - Updated based on your comment clarification

As I understand your question, you want to be able to construct a POST request behind the scenes but let the browser post it so that the browser is redirected to the actual page it is posted, leaving your Elm app behind.

You could build up the form in Elm but keep it hidden, then when you want to trigger it, pass the form ID to a port which performs the form submission.

```elm
type alias Model =
    { foo : String }

view model =
    div []
        [ Html.form
            [ id "my-form"
            , action "https://requestb.in/1crya751"
            , method "POST"
            , style [ ( "display", "none" ) ]
            ]
            [ input [ type_ "text", name "foo", value model.foo ] []
            ]
        , div []
            [ button [ onClick SubmitForm ] [ text "Submit" ] ]
        ]

type Msg
    = SubmitForm

update msg model =
    case msg of
        SubmitForm ->
            model ! [ submitForm "my-form" ]

port submitForm : String -> Cmd msg
```

Your javascript could look something like this (albeit with some error handling in case the id doesn't exist):

```js
var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen()
app.ports.submitForm.subscribe(function(formId) {
    document.getElementById(formId).submit();
});
```

Here is a [working example of this on ellie-app.com](https://ellie-app.com/43VbwSKMH4Fa1/4). It posts the form to requestb.in so you can see what has been posted [by going here](https://requestb.in/1crya751?inspect).

The reason I'm recommending a hidden form instead of trying to use the standard `Http` packages is because it sounds like you want the browser to be redirected to whatever form you are posting to. You couldn't really achieve the same thing by using the `Http` packages.

Comment: Well, almost. The problem is I want to programatically submit it (and I also want to set it's data to something else). I'm guessing since there's no way to do side-effecty things in Elm my only choice is writing this code in JS and then using a port to call it, right?

Comment: I've updated the answer based on your clarification.